# Google Plus links to Stack Exchange questions and answers

Tags: google-plus

If I go to Google Plus and share a link to a question here on a Stack Exchange site, then it works and I get a preview of the question page when I compose the Google Plus post. I'm talking about a post like [this one](https://plus.google.com/108957994038017966408/posts/gRnx9BCLGFU), which links to

> https://serverfault.com/q/199569/14103

However, if I do the same with a direct link to an answer, then it doesn't work. An example is [this post](https://plus.google.com/108957994038017966408/posts/GK5om2YsbZV), where I tried to link to this answer:

> https://serverfault.com/a/343603/14103

That showed up as a simple link with no thumbnail from the site. Does anybody know why this is so? From looking at the site with `wget`, both links redirect to the page with the full text.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a Stack Exchange support issue. Such questions should be asked at [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @AlE. I would say it's more a question about how Google Plus works than a Stack Exchange support question.

Answer (score 6):

Google is unable to read the page via the short link to the answer. On first sight, the headers appear to be identical to the question short link. For [the question](http://web-sniffer.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fserverfault.com%2Fq%2F199569) Server Fault responds:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: /questions/199569/where-to-maintain-central-source-repository
```

...but [for the answer](http://web-sniffer.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fserverfault.com%2Fa%2F343603):

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: /questions/13267/git-and-mercurial/343603#343603
```

The only real difference is the `#fragment` in the redirect URL. Also, when using `bit.ly` URLs to test redirection [with](http://bit.ly/ttA6vD) and [without](http://bit.ly/sE65gN) such fragment, Google gives the same results. So it's a Google thing.

As an aside, note that any Google tool that requests the page chokes on the short link - `http://serverfault.com/a/199572`:

**Rich Snippets Testing Tool:**

- http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=http%3A%2F%2Fserverfault.com%2Fa%2F199572&view=
- Reports 'empty page'

**Google mobile viewer:**

- http://www.google.com/gwt/x?u=http%3A%2F%2Fserverfault.com%2Fa%2F199572
- Reports 'HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.'

No good answer from Google as to why. They say it could be ['caused by an issue with web server configuration, an issue with your hosting provider or even an issue with their ISP'](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=1a2266a505794a99&hl=en#fid_1a2266a505794a990004abe591e7023d). Might take a question on Meta Stack Overflow to resolve?

--

**Update:** [filed as a bug on Meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117180/google-plus-unable-to-read-short-links-to-stack-exchange-answers).

--

**Update:** [resolved on Google's side](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=1a2266a505794a99&hl=en#fid_1a2266a505794a990004abe591e7023d).

Comment: Hmmm. I thought I had tested the link with and without the fragment and got the same result, but I guess not.  Testing http://bit.ly/ttA6vD [w. fragment] and http://bit.ly/sE65gN [w/o fragment] displays the observed behavior on G+. So it's a Google thing.